# CSS sticky footer with extra element

Tags: html, css, footer, sticky-footer

I'm trying to create a website on my own for my art portfolio and I ran across http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/. I'm having trouble adding an extra element for it.

I have the following HTML structure:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" ... />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="layout.css" ... />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <p>Your website content here.</p>
        <div class="push"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
        <p>Copyright (c) 2008</p>
    <img src="image.png>    
    </div>
</body>
```

And the following style.css:

```
.wrapper {
position: relative;
width: 800px;
margin: 0 auto -50px;
}

.footer {
position: relative;
width: 100%;
margin: 0 auto;
padding: 0;
background-color:#000000;
text-align:center;
}

.footer img {
position: relative;
width: 400px;
top: -238px;
margin: 0 auto;
} 

.footer a {
color: #fff;
text-decoration: underline;
border: 0;
}

.footer p {
position: absolute;
left: 0;
bottom: 4px;
width: 100%;
padding: 0;
color: #fff;
font: 0.8em arial,sans-serif;
}
```

with the layout.css:

```
* {
margin: 0;
}
html, body {
height: 100%;
}
.wrapper {
min-height: 100%;
height: auto !important;
height: 100%;
margin: 0 auto -50px; /* the bottom margin is the negative value of the footer's        height */}
.footer { height: 50px; /* .push must be the same height as .footer */} 

.push {
height: -100px; /* .push must be the same height as .footer */
}
```

I set the image negative so that it will overlap the main content when the window is resized. Also, I would like a sticky bottom "border" right below the image. However, no matter how much I mess with the margins or heights, I cannot get rid of the negative space that the above code creates. Do you have any suggestions?

**I figured it out.
The sticky-footer tutorial makes a sticky footer that stops at the border of the main body. What I wanted was a sticky footer that was a top "layer" that will go over the main body AND have a border element on the bottom.
I should not have used the 'top:-238px'.  Instead, I nested a class under footer in html and css.

```
<div class="footer">        
    <img src="Image.png" width="400" height="238" />
    <div class="bottom-border">
        <p>Copyright (c) 2008</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

and

```
.footer img {
position: relative;
width: 400px;
margin: 0 auto;} 

.bottom {
position: relative;
width: 100%;
height: 20px;
margin: 0 auto 0;
padding: 0;
text-align:center;
background-color: #000000;}
```

Then, per sticky-footer's instructions in the 'layout.css' comments, I kept the .wrapper, .footer, .push height's all the same.**

Comment: Can you make a http://jsfiddle.net to demonstrate the problem?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you're trying to do with the image and resizing the window? Doing `top: -238px` just doesn't look good.

Comment: I'd like to place my logo as a "layer" on top of everything, so that it shows above anything else. Depending on browser window size, I'd like my logo to be a "sticky footer". The problem lies when I use the settings from the tutorial, it creates a negative space below the logo + black bar area.

Comment: btw, you need to add a doctype to your html.  That'll determine how your page reacts.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/kagawa_leah/WqNEj/ And thank you Jared and U-DON for replying so quickly! -leah

Comment: JayC - thanks, I just added a sample of code, not the whole thing. Any ideas on how to get rid of the negative space? -leah

Comment: Are you talking about the black area under the image in the footer? your image is causing that.  You might want to position your footer relatively and then position your image absolutely off of that.

Comment: JayC -thanks for looking again. I DO want the black area under the footer, however, I do not want the negative space UNDER the footer. So it should be picture+black bar that is sticky relative to the bottom of the browser. However, right now the picture+black bar is followed by "empty space" or rather the background. So it IS acting "sticky", it does move with the resizing. It's just floating about 200 pixels above where it should be. I can't tell for sure, but I think the top:-238 is also causing it to push down 238 on the bottom as well. How can I counteract that? -leah

Comment: I put it into jsfiddle but it's best scene when it's in a browser so that you can see the floating/resizing issue. Unfortunately, it's not hosted yet, so I cant provide a link. -leah

Comment: I did look at it again in Chrome, IE9, and Firefox 8.x.  I think I'm missing something.  If it's an issue IE 8 or below, I'm not quite equipped (well I *might* be, I just don't want to fire up my VM).

Comment: JayC - Thank you for being so helpful. Can you describe what you were seeing? Does the black border extend all the way to the bottom? I've checked in Chrome, IE9, FF, etc... On every browser, the black border does not extend to the bottom. As it is, I set the border size to 50px. However, if I adjust the margins or heights, I can get a bigger black border on the bottom (enough to fill the negative space). But I cant get it down to an exact 50px. Basically anything less than the height of the picture, will create negative space.

Comment: I figured it out. The [sticky-footer](http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer) tutorial makes a sticky footer that stops at the border of the main body. What I wanted was a sticky footer that was a top "layer" that will go over the main body AND have a border element on the bottom.   @U-DON you were right, I should not have used the 'top:-238px'.  Instead, I took the '<div="footer"> and places it outside (below) the '<body>'. (continued)

Comment: Then, per [sticky-footer](http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer)'s instructions in the 'layout.css' comments, I kept the .wrapper, .footer, .push height's all the same. @JayC Thank you so much for your help. Now, my problem is that the page is too long, haha. Any ideas? =)

Answer (score 0):

Bit late but I can answer it anyway :) The problem is occurring as even though your image is relatively placed above the footer it still occupies the same place in the page. You want to use `position:absolute;`.

[Here it is working](http://jsfiddle.net/WqNEj/17/)

I made the following changes:

```
.footer img { 
  position:absolute; 
}

.footer p {
  position: relative;
  height:4em;
}
```

Using `position:absolute;` will place the element in the position of the last non-static (default) element and remove it from the 'flow of the page'. So in this case it places it at `.footer` and takes it out of the page so it doesn't take up any space anymore.

EDIT: Also I broke the centering by changing it to absolute as `margin:0 auto;` won't work on `position:absolute;` elements. Add these rules to fix that.

```
.footer img {
  left:50%;
  margin-left:-200px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have easiest solution for sticky footer. Please simple add height: 100% on body and html. Then wrapper display: table . For adding element you can add any content/element inside of .w1 element .

And its footer flexible too.

Here is the code

```css
html{height:100%;}
body{
    margin:0;
    height:100%;
  background: #ccc;
}
#wrapper{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    display:table;
    margin:0 auto;
}
#footer{
    width:100%;
    overflow:hidden; /*for FF on Windows 7*/
    display:table-footer-group;
    height:1%;
  background: #333;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper"> <!-- table -->
    <div class="w1">
        <p>header and content of the page</p>
    </div>
    <div id="footer"> <!-- table-footer-group -->
            <p>footer content</p>
    </div>
</div>
```